# When can i use EF4's 'Include FK Columns in the Model'?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm a little confused about EF4, and the EF homepage doesn't help me.

1. Is EF4 a separate download or is it a part of VS2010?
2. What version of EF is native in VS2010?

The reason I'm asking is because I created a .Net 3.5 project in VS2010 (.Net 4.0 is not yet on the production server) and when I went to check the checkbox 'Include FK Columns in the Model' it's gray and says I cannot use it.
Is it because of me targeting 3.5, is my EF version maybe not 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is EF4 a separate download or is it a part of VS2010?

```
 Its a part of VS2010 only
```

.Net 3.5 project in VS2010 - But also it creates for `Version 1 of Entity Framework`

if you go with .Net 4.0 in VS2010 - the `second version of Entity Framework` is used there.

Note: `there were some problems in FK on the Version 1 of Entity Framework`

Comment: thanks very much, so EF4 is used with .net 4, and EF1 is used with .Net 3.5?

Comment: And with 'the second version of EF' you mean 'EF4' right? Because the've done only version 1 and 4, and 2 and 3 don't exist, am i right?

Comment: You are right Michael, there a re no EF 2 &3 versions. Microsoft in abid to align the product releases with Framework 4.0 release named the EF as EF 4.0 You can find out about the impact of include FK in model in my blogpost http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2010/09/entity-framework-part-3-query.html